# What does yum's "Updating for dependencies" mean?

Tags: fedora, yum

Sometimes when I update my software with `yum update`, the summary of packages to be updated displays two lists: "Updating" and "Updating for dependencies".  The packages in the "Updating for dependencies" lists were previously installed.  Why is there a separate list of packages like this?  What does this mean for these packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are run-time dependencies in the packages you're actually trying to update (meaning the software you asked for either uses them directly or uses them indirectly through a secondary package that does use the given dependency).

The newer versions of the packages you're trying to go to will sometimes link against specific versions of the software they depend on or be designed with a particular software version in mind so "Updating for Dependencies" means that in order to have the software you requested be installed/updated it needs to upgrade these other packages otherwise the software you *did* request may behave erratically (if at all).

The analogous concept in the Windows world are software products or patches thereof that require particular service packs already be installed. In other words, the software has a run-time *dependency* on that service pack.

As a more direct example, many applications list glibc as a dependency. If you currently have one version of glibc but try to install a version that was compiled against an updated version, yum will automatically figure out (via metadata) that it needs to update glibc *then* install the package you asked for.

As for why it's itemized separately, it's purely for clarity. If `yum` just suddenly showed you a huge list of software it was about to install, you might say "No, no no, that's not what I asked you to do at all!" and think something went wrong (like a bug or something). Itemizing them separately as dependencies let's you know "No, everything's fine, we just need to update these packages to get to the one you asked for."

IIRC there's also a "Install for dependency" category which lists new software differently so you can see when it gets introduced through a system update versus just when it forced an update of an already installed package.

Comment: Yes, I understand what dependencies are and "Installing for dependencies" makes sense.  However, since I'm updating all the software on my system, shouldn't these be updated regardless of what dependencies they satisfy?

Comment: `yum` is using the same programming logic in `yum update` as it would in say `yum update httpd` (which is an element of good programming design, imo) the only difference is that `yum update` targets all of your installed packages. Since it has to itemize it for restricted installs so that you can identify potential problems, it will need to do that for the more generic target.

Comment: So essentially it's an artifact of efficient program design

Comment: It's an artifact of code re-use which is an element of good programming because it reduces the number of lines of original code.

Answer (score 1):

The "Updating for dependencies" is exactly that - packages that must be updated due to specific version dependencies of packages that are being updated either at your request or due to other dependencies. For example: an update to package `a` requires a new package `d` which you didn't have earlier. The latest version of package `d` available has a version dependency on package `c`. You have version 1 of `c` installed, but `d` requires version 1.2. So `d` is "Installing for dependencies" and `c` is "Updating for dependencies".

Comment: But since I'm updating my whole system, shouldn't `c`  get updated regardless of what dependency it satisfies?  If there's a newer version, it gets installed, no?

Comment: So it happened to get pulled in by a dependency before it was evaluated on it's own. It's on the list to get updated, does it really matter where on that list it is?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.  I'm just curious if it signifies anything more.

Comment: Nope. Just that.

Answer (score 1):

- You have `package A version 1` which requires `package`B`, version 1`.
- You're upgrading `package A` to `version 2`, but that package needs `package B, version 2`.
- So, yum upgrades `package B` to `version 2` automatically and tells you it's upgrading `package B`, `for dependencies`.